# How to determine places of precision needed when taking product of two numbers?

Tags: products

If I have two numbers 0.01 and 0.002 (one with two decimals of precision and the other with three decimals), how can I determine how many decimals of precision are needed for the potential result of 0.00002?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out there is a rule regarding this:

> [Multiplication of a Decimal Number by another Decimal Number](https://www.mathsteacher.com.au/year7/ch06_decimals/09_mult_dec/dec.htm)

The rule states that you can simply count the number of decimals in two numbers and their product will have the precision of the sum of the decimals of those two numbers.

For instance:

```
 0.02    (two decimals)
x0.003   (three decimals)
========
 0.00006 (five decimals)
```

Answer (score 0):

In usual usage, $0.01$ and $0.002$ each have one digit of precision.  The leading zeros just position the decimal point.  Their product should also be quoted with one digit of precision, which is $0.00002$, because the rule is you quote the lower number of digits in your result.

Comment: I may be misusing terminology. Assume I'm not really talking about "significant digits". The precision of `0.00002` would be 5 decimals in my case

Comment: No.  $0.00002$ would have an allowable error of $\pm0.000005$.  The $2$ is significant.  Any other significant digits would have to be to the right of the $2$.  From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) Leading zeros are never significant: 0.02, 001.887, 0.000515  Are you just asking how many decimals are needed to store the number?